# How to add already created label to fedex pickup

Tags: php, fedex, easypost

I'm creating label, and everything works well.
But how can I connect an already created label to FEDEX pickup.

```
try {
                /*
                 * Per explicit request fromthe FROM
                 * address should always be the address of their headquarters
                 */

                /** @var Address $fromAddress */
                $fromAddress = Address::create([
                    "street1" => $params['street'],
                    "street2" => "",
                    "city" => $params['city'],
                    "state" => $params['state'],
                    "zip" => $params['zipCode'],
                    "country" => $params['country'],
                    "company" => $from['name'],
                    "phone" => $from['phone']
                ]);
                if (!$fromAddress->valid()) return self::jsonError('There was an error configuring your shipment. Please try again.');

                /** @var Address $toAddress */
                $toAddress = Address::create([
                    "street1" => $params['toStreet'],
                    "street2" => "",
                    "city" => $params['toCity'],
                    "state" => $params['toState'],
                    "zip" => $params['toZipCode'],
                    "country" => $params['toCountry'],
                    "company" => $params['toName'],
                    "phone" => $params['toPhone']
                ]);
                if (!$toAddress->valid()) return self::jsonError('Address of the requested destination is invalid. Please choose another');

                /** @var Parcel $parcel */
                $parcel = Parcel::create(array(
                    "length" => 13,
                    "width" => 11,
                    "height" => 2,
                    "weight" => 1,
                    "predefined_package" => "FedExPak"
                ));
                if (!$parcel->valid()) return self::jsonError('There was a problem validating parcel dimensions.');

                /** @var Shipment $shipment */
                $shipment = Shipment::create([
                    "to_address" => $toAddress,
                    "from_address" => $fromAddress,
                    "parcel" => $parcel,
                    "options" => [
                        "print_custom_1" => 'Case ' . $project->caseId->get()
                    ]
                ]);
                if (!$shipment->valid()) return self::jsonError('There was a problem creating a valid shipment. Please try again.');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return self::jsonError('There was a problem contacting the shipping service.' . $e->getMessage());
            }

            try {
                // determine rate(s)
                $shipment->get_rates();
                $shippingService = 'FEDEX_2_DAY';
                $defaultService = 'FEDEX_2_DAY';

                if (in_array($params['provide_option'], ['FedEx Dropoff', 'Dropoff'])) {
                    $shippingCarrier = 'FedEx';
                    $defaultCarrier = 'FedEx';
                }
                foreach ($shipment->rates as $rate) {
                    /** @var Rate $rate */
                    if ($rate->carrier == $shippingCarrier && $rate->service == $shippingService) $shippingRate = $rate;
                    else if ($rate->carrier == $defaultCarrier && $rate->service == $defaultService) $defaultRate = $rate;
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return self::jsonError('There was a problem determining shipping rates for the given shipping options. Please contact your customer representative.' . $e->getMessage());
            }

            // buy label
            try {
                if ($shippingRate == null) {
                    // go with default rate if available or try to buy the lowest rate for available carriers
                    $shippingRate = ($defaultRate != null) ?
                        $defaultRate : $shipment->lowest_rate($carriers);
                }
                $shipment->buy(['rate' => $shippingRate]);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return self::jsonError('There was a problem creating the shipment. Please review your shipping information.' . $e->getMessage());
            }

$_SESSION['createdShipment'] = $shipment;
```

here I am trying to add an already created label to pickup
`$_SESSION['createdShipment']` it works on condition. seen in code
but i get error `Unable to create pickup, the carrier associated with the batch shipments is inconsistent.`

```
try {
            $mindate = $params['pickup-date-from'] . " " . $params['pickup-time-from'];
            $maxdate = $params['pickup-date-to'] . " " . $params['pickup-time-to'];

            if(!empty($params['addressPickup']) AND count($params['addressPickup']) == 4){
                $address = Address::create([
                    "street1" => $params['addressPickup']['pickup_street'],
                    "street2" => $params['street2'],
                    "city"    => $params['addressPickup']['pickup_city'],
                    "state"   => $params['addressPickup']['pickup_state'],
                    "zip"     => $params['addressPickup']['pickup_zipCode'],
                    "country" => $params['country'],
                    "company" => $from['name'],
                    "phone"   => $from['phone']
                ]);

                $shipment = $_SESSION['createdShipment'];
            }else{
                $address = Address::create([
                    "street1" => $params['street'],
                    "street2" => $params['street2'],
                    "city"    => $params['city'],
                    "state"   => $params['state'],
                    "zip"     => $params['zipCode'],
                    "country" => $params['country'],
                    "company" => $from['name'],
                    "phone"   => $from['phone']
                ]);
            }

            // Cancel FedEx Pickup if has been bought   
            $this->requestCancelFedExPickup($params, $user, $project, $db, $api, $accountConfig, $oldsession);

            $pickup = \EasyPost\Pickup::create(array(
                "address" => $address,
                "shipment" => $shipment,
                "reference" => "fedex_pickup_refr",
                "min_datetime" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($mindate)),
                "max_datetime" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($maxdate)),
                "is_account_address" => false,
                "instructions" => ""
            ));

            if (!$pickup->valid()) {
                $this->updateProjectCrmByShipmentAndPickup($project, $params, $api, $fromAddress, $toAddress, $shipment);
                return self::jsonError('There was a problem creating a valid pickup. Please try again.');
            }

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->updateProjectCrmByShipmentAndPickup($project, $params, $api, $fromAddress, $toAddress, $shipment);
            return self::jsonError(
            'There was a problem of the Pickup creation. Please contact your  customer representative.',
            ['easy-post' => $e->getMessage()]
        ); }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing often means that either the shipment hasn't been bought or that the pickup and the shipment label are associated with different carriers (eg: label is for UPS but you are trying to schedule a FedEx pickup.)

If you continue to see this error, you can reference the API docs here: https://www.easypost.com/docs/api#pickups or email support@easypost.com - the support team is great at finding what is causing errors like these.